# subtract n times int value

Tags: c++, for-loop, subtraction

My code subtract n times a quantity:

```
int op = 0,quan,numbers,many;
cout << "Quantity to substract: " << endl;
        cin >> quan;
        cout << "Times to subs quantity:" << endl;
        cin >> many;
        for(int count = 1; count <= many; count++)
        {
            cout << "Insert " << count << " Number" << endl;
            cin >> numbers;                 
            op = quan - numbers;
        }
cout << "Total: " << op << endl;
```

But is not working.

**Program Run:**

```
Quantity to substract:
10
Times to subs quantity:
5
Insert 1 Number:
1
Insert 2 Number:
1
Insert 3 Number:
1
Insert 4 Number:
1
Insert 5 Number:
1
Total:
9
```

Total should be `5`

Could you support me with this problem? Thank you

Comment: Using `op = quan - numbers;` you calculate only the last entered `number` in the loop. You should set `op = quan;` once outside the loop, and write `op = op - numbers;` inside the loop.

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even some quick [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the goal here is to subtract all 5 numbers from `quan`. The code in question subtracts only the last one.

To subtract all numbers, initialize the result variable to the first number:

```
op = quan;
```

and in the loop, subtract from the result variable:

```
op = op - numbers; // alternatively: op -= numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because your substract from `quan` without using the previous value of `op`.
in your code each time you make : `op = quan - numbers` you lose the previous obtained state.

```cpp
int op = 0,quan,numbers,many;
cout << "Quantity to substract: " << endl;
        cin >> quan;
        cout << "Times to subs quantity:" << endl;
        cin >> many;
        // make op take the value of quan
        op = quan;
        for(int count = 1; count <= many; count++)
        {
            cout << "Insert " << count << " Number" << endl;
            cin >> numbers;        
            // substract from op           
            op = op - numbers;
        }
cout << "Total: " << op << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int op = 0,quan,numbers,many;
cout << "Quantity to substract: " << endl;
        cin >> quan;
        cout << "Times to subs quantity:" << endl;
        cin >> many;
        for(int count = 1; count <= many; count++)
        {
            cout << "Insert " << count << " Number" << endl;
            cin >> numbers;                 
            op = quan - numbers;
            quan = op; // Add this so that new value is assigned to quan
        }
cout << "Total: " << op << endl;
```